# Replication of RabbitMQ queues into different node(upgraded)

Tags: queue, rabbitmq, cluster-computing, message-queue, rabbitmq-exchange

I have one RabbitMQ cluster which consists of 3 nodes (**each node has : Rabbitmq version :3.3.5, Erlang R14B0** ). Let's call this as Group1. Each node has n number of queues.

I have another cluster with set of 3 nodes with specifications as **RabbitMQ 3.6.6, Erlang R16B03-1**.Let's call this as Group2.

I need to replicate the queue structure of Group1 (node 1,node 2,node 3)  exactly for Group2(node 1,node 2,node 3).

Is there any easy way to perform this without having to add each queue explicitly. Please suggest some  measures.

Thank you.

Regards,

Shweta

Comment: I think you can export queue, bindings and exchange declaration to a file and re-store in new setup easyly